# Possible to estimate completion status/percentage with following information in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am doing a large update and I was checking to see if there was some way I can evaluate how far along it is rather than just looking at the spinner.

For reference:

1. The insert statement looks something like this:

   `INSERT IGNORE INTO table_to SELECT * FROM table_from`
2. The `table_to` has about 2.8B rows.
3. The `table_from` has about 157M rows.

In other words, I'm inserting 157M rows into a table that already has 2.8B rows.

The status when doing `select * from information_schema.processlist where db='history'` just says `Sending data`. When doing `show engine innodb status;` I get the following information:

```
2651250 lock struct(s), 
heap size 418554064, 
166033510 row lock(s), 
undo log entries 35625719
MySQL thread id 5271106, 
OS thread handle 47283734066944, 
query id 906968734 10.194.1.122 avails 
Sending data
```

It does say 166M rows locked -- does it have to lock every single row (2.8B) in order to do the insert? In other words, it's less than 10% done? Or is that a wrong reading of it? And is there any way to evaluate 'how far along the query is' ?

Comment: Insert by small chunks and check what chunk is processed. For example, insert by 10k rows chunks with removing them from `table_from`, and check the amount of remaining rows in this table from another connection.

Comment: @Akina yea...that would have been a good idea. Too late now though -- as the ROLLBACK would take forever to clear out those 35M undo log entries (probably at least 24 hours)